# Counting multiple specific letters in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula, counting

I need to count a series of letters within a cell. Each is separated by a comma. Example:

CM23721 1066    H,H,H,H
CM23722 1022    L,L,L,L,MH,MH,MH,MH,MH,MH,MH,L
CM23723 1094    H

I would really like a formula to count how many times particular phrases (H,L,MH,M) appear in each cell

This is not my data it would seem that a chimp has put it together before I got my hands on it other wise I'd have just counted this data as I went along but hey ho.

Any help would be great. I am not very good with VBA at all but with a good walkthrough I could do it.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in ColumnA starting Row2, please try adding `H` into B1, `L`, into C1, `MH` into D1 and `M` into  E1, then in B2 copied across and down:

```
=(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,"")))/LEN(B$1)
```

Note this counts the `M` in `CM372n` and counts `H` whether on its own or as part of `MH`.

To avoid double counting `H`, after the formulae have been populated change B2 to:

```
=(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,"")))/LEN(B$1)-D2
```

and copy down to suit.

Comment: Thanks that works great however when I copy across and down the formula won't automatically move the ranges (blue outlined box and green outlined box) I have to manually move them. Is there a way around this??

Comment: Remove the `$` from the ranges.

Comment: Thanks that's really helped. I've had to modify it a little to fit the sheet I'm working on but it's saved me alot of time. Thanks again

Comment: When I drag the formula down it doesn't automatically move the blue and green boxes onto the next cells

Comment: Yeah the adapted one. To identify the ranges they are in blue and green boxes